# Checking scratch directory of Impala

Tags: emr, impala

I am using Impala on Amazon EMR.
Is there a way to check what is the current scratch directory that impala is using to write intermediate results ? I know this is defaulted to /tmp/impala-scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current scatch dir in Impala's web page under tab varz, which normally uses port 25000. 
[image]